# Impossible to get working google-authenticator 2fa with Raspbian Os Lite (bookworm)

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, openssh

I have used the official last version imager with the official last version of raspbian os lite. I have installed google authenticator dozen of times sucessfully but in this case I cant figure out how to get work this thing.

I follow the usual steps (for example https://www.turbogeek.co.uk/google-authentication-mfa-on-linux/) and when I try to login with my current password I receive "Permission denied, please try again.".

The output of `journalctl -xeu ssh.service` is :

```
Feb 05 13:29:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit ssh.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit ssh.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3991.
Feb 05 13:29:26 raspberrypi sshd[9458]: Connection closed by authenticating user walo 192.168.1.69 port 34034 [preauth]
Feb 05 13:29:26 raspberrypi sshd[9470]: PAM (sshd) illegal module type: KbdInteractiveAuthentication
Feb 05 13:29:26 raspberrypi sshd[9470]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...yes]
Feb 05 13:29:26 raspberrypi sshd[9470]: PAM (sshd) no module name supplied
Feb 05 13:29:29 raspberrypi sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[9470]: Invalid verification code for walo
Feb 05 13:29:30 raspberrypi sshd[9470]: Failed password for xxx from 192.168.1.69 port 42544 ssh2
```

I change the order of the .so line in configuration and nothing. The only solution is to delete the line with the module of google auth from configuration and password work again without f2a of course.

It's a bug? Something changes in bookworm? I installed bookworm on a PC and follow the same steps and get f2a work as expected. Maybe raspbian has an special procedure to make it work?

UPDATE

I decided to use the legacy image of raspbian os lite based in Debian Bullseye and everything works ok! Whats going on with the new image? I search issues and solution for hours and hours and found nothing.